# NextJS: SASS styles are not applied in AMP pages

Tags: reactjs, sass, next.js, amp-html

SASS styles are not being applied to AMP pages. However, the SASS styles are applied to normal webpage as expected. In the nextjs docs, there is no guideline on SASS styles for AMP pages. Do we need to configure `next.config.js`?

```
import React from "react";
import { useAmp } from 'next/amp';
import styles from "about.module.scss";
export const config = { amp: 'hybrid' }
const About =() => {
const isAmp = useAmp();
 return(
        <>
        {!isAmp ? 
                <div className={styles.red}>Working</div>
            :   <div className={styles.red}>Not Working</div>
        }
        </>
}
export default About;
```

**EDITED:_document.js**

```
MyDocument.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  // Render app and page and get the context of the page with collected side effects.
  const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets();
  const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

  ctx.renderPage = () =>
    originalRenderPage({
      enhanceApp: (App) => (props) => sheets.collect(<App {...props} />),
    });

  const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);

  return {
    ...initialProps,
    // Styles fragment is rendered after the app and page rendering finish.
    styles: [...React.Children.toArray(initialProps.styles), sheets.getStyleElement()],
  };
};
```

Comment: Is there an SASS processor for AMP? I don't think so. Is the generated CSS for your AMP runtime failing?

Comment: @JayGray we are using material ui, i could see the material ui styles in the Server side rendered page. I don't see the styles which is been written in `module.scss`. I have edited my question with `_document.js`.Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue in next.js. Related to https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/10549 and https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7121